# Проблема с create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

После установки create-react-app  делаю npm start.
Вылезает вот такая ошибка
[image: ռեա]

Обновил npm,node
Переустановил npm,node
Перезагрузил комп

Ничего не помогло, хотя раньше create-react-app у меня работало нормально.

Также на что то ругается phpshtorm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот обсуждение вашей проблемы на гитхабе https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908. Там в каментах есть решение/костыль.

Comment: убедись, что порт не занят